# Getting SOAP error when parsing WSDL from an API when the website hosting has been changed

Tags: php, soap

Switched hosting and I have been encountering a SOAP error. The PHP version I am running is 7.3 and the previous hosting was 7.2. The URL that the soap client is trying to access is open and allows anyone to access it. SOAP has been enabled on cPanel.

```
<?php 
        try{

            $soapclient = new SoapClient('http://url/Schedule_service.asmx?re_Status&WSDL');
            $param = array('TheatreId'=>101,'FilmId'=>0);
            $response = $soapclient->FnSchedule_Film_Theatre_Status($param);
            $coming_result = json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
```

The error message is displayed on the website is, where URL is the soap client url:

`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://url' failed to load external entity 'http://url'`

Comment: Can you access `url` from the new hosting server? Is `url` defined in a public DNS or must be configured somewhere? In other words, have you excluded this being a network issue not a PHP one?

Comment: @Bogdan url can be accessed from anywhere, it has open access for now. It was working with the previous hosting provider. I don't think it is a network issue according to my knowledge

Comment: Are there any linked W3C definitions in the WSDL file? The W3C forces a loading delay on some definitions to reduce traffic on their definition servers. You could also check all other links to definitions (mostly xsd). The PHP `SoapClient` class has problems with loading delayed definitions.